# Object.length undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an javascript object of arrays like,

```
var coordinates = {
     "a": [
         [1, 2],
         [8, 9],
         [3, 5],
         [6, 1]
     ],

         "b": [
         [5, 8],
         [2, 4],
         [6, 8],
         [1, 9]
     ]
 };
```

but `coordinates.length` returns undefined.
[Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/3wzb7jen/).

Comment: An object doesn't have any length, arrays does

Comment: What length did you expect? 2? 8? 16?

Comment: I found this question while investigating why in my case an actual array assigned to [] and then having one item pushed to it, has a length of undefined.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That's because `coordinates` is `Object` not `Array`, use [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```
var coordinates = {
     "a": [
         [1, 2],
         [8, 9],
         [3, 5],
         [6, 1]
     ],

     "b": [
         [5, 8],
         [2, 4],
         [6, 8],
         [1, 9]
     ]
 };

for (var i in coordinates) {
  console.log(coordinates[i]) 
}
```

or [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
var coordinates = {
  "a": [
    [1, 2],
    [8, 9],
    [3, 5],
    [6, 1]
  ],

  "b": [
    [5, 8],
    [2, 4],
    [6, 8],
    [1, 9]
  ]
};

var keys = Object.keys(coordinates);

for (var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
  console.log(coordinates[keys[i]]);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

`coordinates` is an object.  Objects in javascript do not, by default, have a `length` property.  Some objects have a length property:

```
"a string - length is the number of characters".length

['an array', 'length is the number of elements'].length

(function(a, b) { "a function - length is the number of parameters" }).length
```

You are probably trying to find the number of `keys` in your object, which can be done via [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
var keyCount = Object.keys(coordinates).length;
```

---

Be careful, as a `length` property can be added to any object:

```
var confusingObject = { length: 100 };
```

Comment: I didn't know `(function(){}).length` is number of arguments. Thanks for your sharing.

Answer (score 8):

http://jsfiddle.net/3wzb7jen/2/

```
 alert(Object.keys(coordinates).length);
```